# SQLAlchemy returns session value instead of database value

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am implementing a Telegram bot, with some data that is recorded in a database using SQLAlchemy.
Sometimes, I am interested in taking a value from one of the fields of the main class I work with, blocking that row to execute some things:

```
self.clock = enumType.CLOCK_END
check : ClockStatus = self.database.session.query(Bot).filter(Bot.id == self.id).with_for_update(nowait=False).first().clock
if (check is ClockStatus.CLOCK_END) : break
```

At this point:

**DATABASE VALUES**:
ID_BOT = 312
CLOCK = CLOCK_RUNNING

**MEMORY VALUES (the object itself):**
ID_BOT = 312
CLOCK (of the variable "clock") = CLOCK_END (just assigned)

(SELF in the code is an object, the Bot itself, loaded from an active session, the same as "self.database.session" in the code. CLOCK is an enumerated value, a label of the object Bot).

The point is that in this session, the value of the "clock" field is different from the one in the database, but SQLAlchemy, when applying that filter, returns the value of the session object (that has the same ID), NOT the value of the one in the database (not updated yet, but I want the old value before updating).

I don't want to read the value that I already have (although theoretically it is the same as it should be in the database, because they are the same type (Bot), with the same ID). Here, SQLAlchemy "is too smart", and what interests me is to read the previous value resident in the database. I'll sync it later.
Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

---

Edit:
Session now is created like:

```
session = Session(autoflush=False)
```

with the same result.

Comment: Assuming `self.database.session` is the same that was used to query `self`, you are facing autoflush, unless you have disabled it. In order to keep the session and database state in sync so that queries return "sane" values SQLAlchemy flushes pending changes in the session to the database before issuing a query.

Comment: Yes, It's the same session to query "self". I didn't disabled it, and try again. I will check out the doc.

Comment: I created session like: session = Session(autoflush=False), and still the same result.

Comment: Finally, I solve it just creating a local session not binded to the object. Thank you for your time.